# autoencoder with tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, mnist, autoencoder

I try to implement Stacked autoencoder with tensorflow. I used the mnist data set and try do reduce the dimension from 784 to 2. I already did it with keras, and its result was good(train error was almost 0.04). However, with this tesorflow code the result is not good(train error was almost 0.4). I don't know why these results are so different. Can you tell me how do I revise it?

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
import tensorflow as tf


(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')

x_train = x_train.reshape(60000,28*28)
x_test = x_test.reshape(10000,28*28)

x_train  = x_train/255.0
x_test = x_test/255.0

x_ = tf.placeholder('float32', [None,784])



#encoder
w1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784,512]))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([512]))
h1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x_, w1) + b1)

w2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([512,128]))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([128]))
h2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h1, w2) + b2)

w0 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([128,2]))
b0 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2]))
h0 = tf.matmul(h2, w0) + b0



#decoder
w_1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2,128]))
b_1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([128]))
h_1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h0, w_1) + b_1)

w_2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([128,512]))
b_2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([512]))
h_2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_1, w_2) + b_2)

w_0 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([512,784]))
b_0 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784]))
h_0 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(h_2, w_0) + b_0)


#cost
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(x_-h_0,2))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.05).minimize(cost)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()


batch_count = int(x_train.shape[0]/256)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
for i in range(2) :
    total_cost = 0
    for j in range(batch_count) :
        batch_xs= x_train[i*256:i*256 + 256,:]
        _, cost_val = sess.run([train_step, cost], feed_dict = {x_ : batch_xs})
        total_cost = total_cost + cost_val
        if j % 20 == 0 :
            print('epoch : %d ,%d / %d , loss : %f , average_loss : %f' %(i+1, j+1, batch_count, cost_val, total_cost/(j+1)))


hidden1, hidden2, encoder = sess.run([h1,h2,h0],feed_dict={x_ : x_test})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your final encoder step has no activation `h0 = tf.matmul(h2, w0) + b0` and thus the loss is remaining at 0.48, after applying relu activation there, i.e. replacing

`h0 = tf.matmul(h2, w0) + b0`  with `h0 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h2, w0) + b0)`, the loss goes down to 0.06 in just two epochs.

[image: After adding activation in the last layer of the encoder]

I also changed the frequency of when in it displays output to fit more data in the Image.

If you have any further queries, comment below.

Comment: [keras_autoencoder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zckx8.jpg) is my another code with keras, and I used the linear function in this case. I think linear activation function means no activation function.  [keras_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mQO5.jpg) is the result of keras code. Can you fine the difference between them??

Comment: Yes, Linear means that no activation, the only difference that I can see is the learning rate, in keras it is by default `0.001` and in your TensorFlow model you have specified it as `0.05`, I have doubts that this would be the cause, but I would recommend trying it. If that doesn't work host your keras code in GitHub because it is a bit hard to debug code from image.

Comment: It didn't work... so do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: @Gwan Sorry, I am unable to figure it out.